You can't remove targetConfigs because the targetConfig for lightningCommunity__Default is needed
Hello,
I did a modification on a LWC, I correctly deployed it in a sandbox but it doesn't work when I deploy it in Production.
This is the issue I have:

You can't remove targetConfigs because the targetConfig for
lightningCommunity__Default is needed

I deleted this part from the LWC configuration part:
<targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="pos" type="String" default="{!Route.pos}" />
            <property
        name="currentTab"
        type="String"
        datasource="yourTransfers,transfersToHandle"
      />
      </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>

Maybe I should keep "targetConfigs" empty?
Like
<targetConfigs>
</targetConfig>

What should I do to be able to deploy correctly my LWC in Production?
Thanks

First, you need to remove thre reference of your LWC it is used in a community. Then remove the property and deploy the updated code,  and it will work. Also, refer to this may help you. -https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5k7SAAQ/lwc-deployment-fails-when-changing-from-single-targetconfig-with-multiple-targets-to-multiple-individual-targetconfigs

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4HEvSAN


It's weird ze need to first remove the reference of the LWC before removing the property, it worked, thank you.

First, you need to remove the reference of your LWC if it is used in a community. Then remove the property and deploy the updated code, and it will work.
Also, refer to this may help you.

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5k7SAAQ/lwc-deployment-fails-when-changing-from-single-targetconfig-with-multiple-targets-to-multiple-individual-targetconfigs
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4HEvSAN

